# Passing and returnging array to the functions

Tags: php

I have created two arrays. I wanna pass these two array to any function. I am beginner with function so tried with rough code to achieve my task. As I have some values in $cntctnum and $cntcttype named array.

```
 $cntctnum      = array();
 $cntcttype     = array();
 $response = array();

 function play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype){
 $contactnumber= $cntctnum[];
 $cntcttype = $cntcttype[];

 // some code to play with array.

 return resultarray();
 }


 $response = play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype);
```

Is this right way to pass function in array?
Is I need to declare $response as array before or when I return resultarray(), it will automatically consider it as array?

Comment: Those really look like misspelling-proof variable names

Comment: My aim is not to correct my spelling... I have created a dummy function for rough idea to my needs..

Comment: Couldn't you come up with simpler names like $array_test or $array_one? in 'cntcttype' it's easy to mispell a letter and raise errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define `$response` as array beforehand, but it might be a good idea to do so anyway depending on what the code afterwards expects.

In your function you don't return a function call `resultarray()` but a new array:

```
function play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype) {
    $contactNumber = $cntctnum; // You don't need the assignment! Note: No brackets here!
    $resultArray = array();
    // Do something here        
    return $resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
$cntctnum      = array();
$cntcttype     = array();
$response = array();

function play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype){
$contactnumber= $cntctnum[]; // don't need []
$cntcttype = $cntcttype[];   // don't need []

// some code to play with array.

return resultarray(); // this is a function?
}


$response = play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype);
```

I would do something like this

```
$cntctnum    = array();
$cntcttype    = array();

function play_with_array($contactnumber, $cntcttype){
    // some code to play with array.
    $response = array($contactnumber,$cntcttype);

    return $response; 
}

$response = play_with_array($cntctnum, $cntcttype);
echo "<pre>".print_r($response,true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, you pass array to a function just like you pass any other variable to a function. The reason to have a function is to have a block of code that can be re-used to perform the same set of calculations, etc.

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do inside your function. If this is something that's repeatable, meaning: compare array 1 vs array 2, get the bigger one, and return some sort of variation of that, then YES, create a function. If you have some code inside your function that is very specific to this page only and to these 2 arrays, you don't need the function. Just write the code inline.

> Is I need to declare $response as array before or when I return resultarray(), it will automatically consider it as array?

No, you don't. If you resultarray variable inside a function is truly an array, you're good to go.